# Invalid number of parameters in Batch but not in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, outlook

I am trying to make a scheduled batch file to run with the volume shadow copy service to copy the outlook.pst file from microsoft outlook.

The commands work properly when i enter them in the command panel but when i setup the same code in a batch file it gives me an invalid number of parameters error in during the second line.

You have to use administrator access on cmd and the batch file for it to even work and i am doing that but i have no clue as to why i get an error only in the batch version but not in cmd?

I found [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/129188/htg-explains-what-are-shadow-copies-and-how-can-i-use-them-to-copy-or-backup-locked-files/) helpful.

Its where i found the batch file which simplifies the process incase anyone is wondering.

Heres the code :

```
CALL MountLatestShadowCopy "C:\MyShadow\"

xcopy /y "C:\MyShadow\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Outlookove datoteke\*.pst" "\\hyp\backup"

RMDIR "C:\MyShadow"

pause
```

Anyone have any ideas as to the cause of my problems? Its supposed to simply copy the .pst file to a server for backup which i will run on a regular schedule.

Outlook is usually the first thing people open when they turn on their computers so i have to use volume shadow copy otherwise getting a copy might be hard on certain computers.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The website would not allow me to post it without a space. it deleted the \ before it if i didnt put a space for some reason. There is no space tho in the code.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it did not allow me to do that. Could have been weird formating.

Comment: Can you post the (verbatim) output of the command? When CMD interprets variables and things, it's visible in the command echo. It might give us a clue.

Comment: That code will not generate an error as you've described.  Only if you have set the `username` variable manually could it generate such an error, or if you have another command called `xcopy.exe` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help. This morning when i came to work i tried running the batch file just in case before i posted anything... And for some reason the batch file now worked? Thanks for the tips tho from foxidrive. Weird? I did not change anything in the code itself.